# How can I do unit test when the input string is set as FileType in argparse for python command line program?

Tags: python, unit-testing, argparse, readline

The code (`file_name.readline()`) will not run if I pass a string file_name in the test program (as expected). I need to test several different files for one method.
Is the only solution not to use FileType but str in argparse?

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='XXX')

    parser.add_argument('file_name', type=argparse.FileType('r'), help='Please choose a file.')
```

Comment: "The code (file_name.readline()) will not run if I pass a string file_name in the test program (as expected)." Why not? Unit tests can easily make files. You could even use [pyfakefs](http://jmcgeheeiv.github.io/pyfakefs/release/)

Comment: Because the input file_name is a string. For it to run in the python environment, I have to add file = open(file_name, 'r'), and read from file. file_name.readline() does not work unless using command line in command prompt.

Comment: Accepting a filename and doing your own `with open` is better python3 practice. FileType is a convenience for small scripts.  See my comments earlier today, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71693694/argparse-versus-bash-redirections-for-input-output-files

Comment: Unittest with files is awkward. If you can't fake it (mock), you have to create test files in a`temp` dir.  I expect that's covered in specialized unittesting books.